# Can Wolverine survive blood-borne diseases?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

Wolverine's unique ability of cell regeneration almost makes him invincible but if he was to suffer from any blood borne disease in particular HIV would he survive? HIV affects the white blood cells in the blood and hence destroys one's immune system, leading to the AIDS condition of ultra sensitivity to other infectious diseases.

Comment: Regeneration of WBC would outrun its destruction..

Comment: aids is not a disease!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like the powers of many comic characters, Wolverine's potential (particularly his healing ability) has fluxed from writer-to-writer depending on the situation.

According to [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Howlett_%28Earth-1610%29), he is immune to all diseases such as cancer or HIV.

> Disease Resistances: Wolverine's healing factor has also extended to his immune system. He is immune to all known Earthly diseases and infections.

According to [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29), however, he only has

> an enhanced resistance to diseases.

While both sites are wikis, the Marvel Universe one is written by Marvel employees, so I would tend to favor their more official description.

So, his body could contract a disease such as HIV or cancer, but his healing factor would likely combat it. Whether or not it could overcome the disease would end up being an issue of severity versus time and how powerful the writer decided to make his healing factor in that particular story.

Comment: He did overcome the Legacy Virus in the animated series (different cannon obviously) which is similar to cancer, but he wasn't immune to it.

Comment: Exactly, the 90s cartoon took a realistic antibody based direction. Wolverine was infected with, and (painfully) overcame the virus through a superior immune system response, developing the antibodies that were then used to immunize the rest of both mutant and human kind. Just like Wolverine can be wounded, but the wound heals.

Answer (score 3):

It's explictly stated in [Uncanny X-Men #421](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_421) that mutants are immune to AIDS.

[image]

This claim is repeated (with a little more explanation) in [Uncanny X-Men #427](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_427). Apparently it's because of the X-gene. Given that Wolverine carries this gene, it follows that he would be immune.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That sounds like satire on ignorance than a legit statement that all mutants can't get HIV or aids. What's her explication on the next page?

Comment: I can't fathom a reason why Marvel would decide mutants can't get HIV.  That's stupendously ridiculous.  But either way, that doesn't answer the question, since there are plenty of other blood borne diseases besides HIV.

Comment: @scott.korin - The question specifically asks about HIV/AIDS. Although this doesn't address every single blood-borne disease, it's still an answer, albeit a partial one.

Comment: @cde - dead on. If it wasn't, than your idea is better than the writers'.

Comment: @cde Taken alone, her statement sounds like an ignorant belief. But not only does Angel also make the claim, the doctor agrees with him. It may not make much sense, but it does appear to be true.

Comment: @ksmarts aside from the specific "can't get aids" phrasing leaving it wide open for debate on HIV still affecting the mutant to a lower degree, or still being a non symptomatic HIV carrier, AND Angel having just been given a healing factor magical cure all, or this being from a single writer's 2003 run and never mentioned again, or that specific writer Chuck Austen always adding nonsensical and panned ideas, no it doesn't.

Comment: @cde - Actually, the frame before simply asks the nurse to screen him for Hepatitis. It doesn't say that mutants are immune.

Comment: @cde It wasn't mentioned again, but is AIDS a common topic in X-Men? What idea wasn't originally just from one writer? Is this more or less nonsensical than a single gene mutation giving a huge variety of physics-defying abilities? I'm not saying that it's a *good* idea, but from what I see here, it looks like the writer intended it to be true. If it hasn't been contradicted elsewhere, then we should presume that it is.